# YAML merging String Process

Tags: python

How to add a process to delete all the previous rows among the rows with duplicate keys only when the parent key is the same?

```py
def yaml_to_merged_yaml():
    combined_yaml = combine_yaml_headers(input_files)
    with open(output_file, 'w') as f:
        lines = combined_yaml.split('\n')
        previous_line = ""  # Store the previous line for insertion

        for i, line in enumerate(lines):
            if ':' in line:
                match = re.match(r'(\s*.*:)(\s*)([^\n]*[^\s])', line)
                if match:
                    line = f"{match.group(1)}{match.group(2)}\"{match.group(3)}\""

            if ':' not in line and previous_line:
                match = re.match(r'(\s*)([^\n]*[^\s])', previous_line)
                if match:
                    line = f"{match.group(1)}{match.group(2)}{line}"
                    previous_line = ""  # Clear the stored previous line

            f.write(line + '\n')
            previous_line = line
```

output:

```
AAA001:
  ol1: "aaa"
  ol1: "bbb"
AAA002:
  ol1: "ccc"
  ol1: "ddd"
```

shoult be

```
AAA001:
  ol1: "bbb"
AAA002:
  ol1: "ddd"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's better to add a variable `parent_key` to store the parent key and checking if the current key is the same as the parent key and if it is, it clears the stored previous line to remove the duplicate and if it's a new parent key, it updates the `parent_key` variable.

```
def yaml_to_merged_yaml():
    combined_yaml = combine_yaml_headers(input_files)
    with open(output_file, 'w') as f:
        lines = combined_yaml.split('\n')
        previous_line = ""  #storing the previous line for insertion
        parent_key = ""  #storing the parent key to check for duplicates

        for i, line in enumerate(lines):
            if ':' in line:
                match = re.match(r'(\s*.*:)(\s*)([^\n]*[^\s])', line)
                if match:
                    line = f"{match.group(1)}{match.group(2)}\"{match.group(3)}\""

                key = line.split(':')[0].strip()  #extract the key from the line

                if key == parent_key:
                    previous_line = ""  #clear the stored previous line if duplicate key
                else:
                    parent_key = key  #update the parent key

            if ':' not in line and previous_line:
                match = re.match(r'(\s*)([^\n]*[^\s])', previous_line)
                if match:
                    line = f"{match.group(1)}{match.group(2)}{line}"
                    previous_line = ""  #clear the stored previous line

            f.write(line + '\n')
            previous_line = line

yaml_to_merged_yaml()
```